# How do I filter values out of a TSQL UNPIVOT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, unpivot

I've got a column oriented table that specifies manufacturing options for a product.  Each option can be a subset of the following choices (' ', 'B','L','R','BX','LX','RX).  The table has 314 columns.  (This is a legacy build and not the way I'd do it today...)

I have a customer request to count the number of times an option was used within a date range.  Getting to the filtered data is not a problem, but getting the column oriented table converted to a countable row-oriented table is challenging my pivot/unpivot skills.

I can get the column names with this (as referenced from http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx)

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max)

select @cols = coalesce(@cols + ',' + quotename(column_name), quotename(column_name))
from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'mfgOptions'
    and data_type = 'char' and character_maximum_length
```

Most of the time, the options have a ' ' value.  I don't want to include these in my pivoted table.
My desired result is a table like:

```
MfgItemID | MfgOptionName | OptionSelection
-------------------------------------------
1000      | option1       | BX
1000      | option2       | B
2000      | option1       | LX
2000      | option3       | RX
```

using the @cols definition above, I created the following UNPIVOT

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)
set @query = N'SELECT MfgItemID, MfgOptionName, OptionSelection
from (SELECT MfgItemID, ' + @cols + '
FROM mfgOptions) a
UNPIVOT (OptionSelection for MfgOptionName IN (' + @cols + ') ) AS u
order by MfgItemID, MfgOptionName'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

This query is executing and appears to mostly do what I need.  However it takes an extremely long time as I have 500,000+ rows in the table.  If I could eliminate all blank options before unpivoting, I think it would run much faster.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to filter field values prior to unpivoting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put a `WHERE` inside the `UNPIVOT` clause and you can't filter out in your subquery that returns `a` because there may be other values on the row that are useful. The best thing I know that you can do is say `WHERE u.OptionSelection <> ' '` after the `UNPIVOT` like so:

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)
set @query = N'SELECT MfgItemID, MfgOptionName, OptionSelection
from (SELECT MfgItemID, ' + @cols + '
FROM mfgOptions) a
UNPIVOT (OptionSelection for MfgOptionName IN (' + @cols + ') ) AS u
WHERE u.OptionSelection <> '' ''
order by MfgItemID, MfgOptionName'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: That's it!  It definitely sped up the query.  And I got the data I wanted.  Thanks!